# Linux .profile overrides other bash commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am loading a script (whiptail) when the root user logs into their Linux server, which works fine.  The thing is, now, when I attempt to run other scripts from the command prompt (or crontab) the initial script is loaded instead, and it looks like the script that I want to run is not.

This is what `~/.profile` looks like:

```
if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi

mesg n
source /root/menu.sh
```

So, when I try to run `bash -lc 'ruby some/other/script.rb` I'm taken into the script that runs at the end of `~/.profile` which is `menu.sh`.  How can I keep this from happening?

Here's what I need to have happen in the long run:

1. The server boots up and takes the user to `/root/menu.sh`
2. There are background scripts that run via `crontab` such as a check in script, job script, etc.

Comment: Why are you using `-l` if you don't want its effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Best-practices: Don't use a login shell unless you need one

When you pass the `-l` argument to bash, you're telling it to behave as a login shell; this includes running the user's `.profile`.

If you don't want that behavior, don't pass `-l`. Thus:

```
bash -c 'ruby some/other/script.rb'
```

That said, there's no advantage to doing that over just invoking `ruby` directly, without any enclosing shell:

```
ruby some/other/script.rb
```

---

#### If you *must* use a login shell...

If you want other effects of running the user's `.profile`, you might set an environment variable to indicate that you want to bypass this behavior:

```
# in the user's login scripts
[ -n "$skip_menu" ] || source /root/menu.sh
```

...and then...

```
skip_menu=1 bash -lc '...your command here...'
```

...or, if being executed without an enclosing shell...

```
env skip_menu=1 bash -lc '...your command here...'
```

Comment: Does it make a difference when running the script through `crontab`?  Simply using `bash -c 'ruby /my/script.rb` within `crontab` isn't working.

Comment: You'd better use POSIX' `.` instead of Bash's `source` in `.profile`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf what's the difference?

Comment: @Godzilla74: In Bash, `source` and `.` are synonyms; but strictly POSIX-compliant shells will choke on `source`: [for best portability, use `.`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_18).